# How to call connect() function on two different address and wait with select to find which address returned fast in c

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I have two IP address for a host and I would like to do a connect call on both of them at the same time and then wait on them with the select(), which ever IP returns first, I would like to connect to that IP. Is there a way to implement this behaviour without threading and only select()/connect() function?

Below is the pseudo code:

```
create_connection()
{
struct addrinfo *adres = NULL;
struct addrinfo h;
struct addrinfo *p = NULL;
int res;

res = getaddrinfo(hostname, NULL, &h, &adres);
for(p=adres;p!=NULL;p=p->next)
 {
 int sock = -1;
 tcp_create_conn(p->ai_addr, &sock, ..);
 } 
}

tcp_create_conn(struct sockaddr *addr, int *sp,..)
{
fd_set my_set;
int res;
addr->sin_port = <default_port>;
*sp = lg_socket(addr->sa_family, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

\\bind

\\enable non blocking

while(connect(*sp,addr,get_len(addr))<0) {
 if (errno == EINOPROGRESS)
  do{
     tv.tv_sec = 5;
     tv.tv_usec = 0;
     FD_ZERO(&myset);
     FD_SET(*sp, &myset);
     res = select(*sp + 1, NULL, &myset, NULL, &tv);
     if (res>0)
      //connection is success
    }while(1)
 }
}
```

I want to pass two address from the getaddrinfo(if we have two address) to tcp_create_conn(addr1, addr2,..) and call connect on both of them and wait for the response, which ever address is returned first, I would want to connect to that address.

Comment: You could set the sockets to nonblocking and let select() handle the state changes.

Comment: can you provide little more detail on that? on how to achieve that. I am already setting my socket to non blocking state, but in the case mentioned above i do it for only one address at a time, i would like to do it for 2 address at the same time, so having trouble doing that.

Comment: You are effectively blocking on select() now. get select() out of the loop. remove the loop, and just remember the state the socket is in. You'll need a *centralised* select() loop, that inspects the sockets states, and ( maybe) adds them to the fd_set, and calls the appropiate function on them, altering the state.

Comment: @wildplasser Request you to explain the same with some kind of pseudo code, I am pretty much new to socket programming so I am finding it difficult to understand the solution you are suggesting. Thanks.

Comment: It is simple: if a call to a socket results in EWOULDBLOCK, you should remembert its state. Next time it select()s as readable you can then take the appropiate action (and maybe alter its state) In any case you should avoid blocking calls (and only block on (a single) select())